# React Validation on password field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

```
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="Password"
          variant="outlined"
        />
```

Need help to create a password validation with onchange function logic?
Please help me with below rules on password validation
Minimum character length of 8 and Maximum character length of 64.
Password composition: at least 1 upper and lower case character, 1 number and 1 special character
Spaces are allowed within the password, but not at the beginning or end of the password
Password does not contain the username

Comment: show us what you have tried. Take a look at [ask] and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to validate a form is the [mui-validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-validate) library.
so you can validate your input simply by wrapping them into a `<ValidationGroup />` component

```
   import { Validate } from 'mui-validate';

export default () => (
    <ValidationGroup>
        <>
            ...
            <Validate name="internal key 1" required>
                <TextField />
            </Validate>
            <Validate name="internal key 2" unique={['a', 'b']}>
                <TextField />
            </Validate>
            <Validate name="internal key 3" regex={/^\d{0,5}$/}>
                <TextField />
            </Validate>
            <Validate name="internal key 4" custom={[(value) => value === 'expected value', 'Custom validation failed!']}>
                <TextField />
            </Validate>
            ...
        </>
    </ValidationGroup>
)
```

for the password strength you can use a normal regular expression similar to this one:

```
const passwordPattern = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,64}$/;
```

Comment: `<Validate name="internal key 3" regex={/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,64}$/}>` this is not working for password field?

Comment: my answer have some basics from official docs...need to be customized obviously

Comment: pls help me with no whitespace at beginning and end along with /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,64}$/;

Comment: you can try with /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,}$/